# image upload problem with ie7

Tags: java, internet-explorer, file-upload

i am uploading image from a simple html form

```
 <form action="../OctetStreamReader" method="post"  accept="image/gif, image/jpeg">
 Your image: <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

and inside OctetStreamReader i am copying the image on server using IOUtils

```
realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH) + "/";
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {
        writer = response.getWriter();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log(OctetStreamReader.class.getName() + "has thrown an exception: "
                + ex.getMessage());
    }

    if (canInsert) {
        // String filename = request.getHeader("X-File-Name");
        String filename = utils.createFileName(ssn, userEmail, userId);
        try {
            ImageCompressor ic= new ImageCompressor();

            is = request.getInputStream();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(realPath + filename));
            logger.info("avalible bytes :" + is.available());
            IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
            logger.info("inserting copied");
```

the code is working absolutely fine in all browsers except IE and especially IE7.
In case of IE7 , a new file is created on the server but with file size 0kb.
and In case of other browsers like chrome,FF,safari , new file is created with the actual size of uploaded image.
i am unable to trace out the problem as the code is not throwing any exception.

Please Help ..

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried using Apache Commons File Upload http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/ ?

Comment: I've added  enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form attribute
and it worked. the file size now is absolutely correct.
but the file is not opening....the windows picture viewer says 
'No Preview available'

Comment: i tried using Apache Commons File Upload and it worked perfectly.
Thanks Luciano

Comment: You are welcome. Put it as an answer so when others come they'll know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried using Apache Commons File Upload and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You should add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your form element.